# Pandas: How to read a CSV with newlines in fields?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV having newlines inside fields. Like:

```
COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4
...
1234567,"New Age Music","Line1
Line2
Line3: an so on",123-456-789
...
```

So it actually has to be read according to number of columns figured out from header. Is it possible in Pandas/Python?

**P.S.** It's MSSQL 2008 dump. Maybe it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas is smart enough to do it for you (if it's properly quoted):

```
In [74]: data
Out[74]: 'COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4\n1234567,"New Age Music","Line1\nLine2\nLine3: an so on",123-456-789'

In [75]: print(data)
COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4
1234567,"New Age Music","Line1
Line2
Line3: an so on",123-456-789

In [76]: pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data))
Out[76]:
      COL1           COL2                           COL3         COL4
0  1234567  New Age Music  Line1\nLine2\nLine3: an so on  123-456-789
```